# Livewire mount suddenly stop receiving parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component that shows a model through route model binding, it was working but suddenly I received the following error:

> **Too few arguments to function Livewire\LivewireManager::mount(), 0 passed in**

Here are samples from my code:

**Routes on web.php**

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/admin/intro-section', \App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminIntroSection::class)->name('admin.intro-section.index');
    Route::get('/admin/intro-section/{id}', \App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminIntroSectionShow::class)->name('admin.intro-section.show');
});
```

**Livewire component class in `Livewire\Admin\`**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\IntroSection;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class AdminIntroSectionShow extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public IntroSection $introSection;
    public $photo;

    protected $rules = [
        'introSection.title' => 'string',
        'introSection.description' => 'string',
        'introSection.link' => 'string',
        'introSection.img_link' => 'string',
        'photo' => 'nullable|image|max:2000',
    ];

    public function update(IntroSection $introSection, Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate();
        if ($this->photo) {
            $filename = $this->photo->store('img', 'public');
            $this->introSection->img_link = $filename;
        }
        $this->introSection->save();
    }

    public function mount($id)
    {
        $this->introSection = IntroSection::where('id', $id)->with(['details'])->first();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.intro-section-show');
    }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Add routes on web.php
2. `php artisan make:livewire Admin\AdminIntroSectionShow`
3. A model named "IntroSection" with the following attributes:

   'title' => (string),
   'description' => (text),
   'link' => (string),
   img_link' => (string)

**Are you using the latest version of Livewire**: Yes

The last time the code worked was before when I finished doing the file upload portion. After that, I tested the file upload which worked. Reloaded the page after being satisfied but now, mount seems not to like it.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I tried removing the update function, passing IntroSection $introsection to mount instead of $id. Nothing seems trivial on the livewire component as far as I'm concerned but here it is anyways:

```
<div>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Intro Section') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <section class="relative container mx-auto px-4">
            <div class="p-4 bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg">
                <form wire:submit.prevent="update" class="md:grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-6">
                <div class="md:col-span-1">
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label class="border-b-2 border-blue-500">Title</label>
                        <div class="text-lg font-medium mt-2">{{ $introSection->title }}</div>
                        <input type="text" name="title" wire:model="introSection.title">
                        @error('title') {{ $message }} @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label class="border-b-2 border-blue-500">Link</label>
                        <div class="text-lg font-medium mt-2">{{ $introSection->link }}</div>
                        <input type="text" name="link" wire:model="introSection.link">
                        @error('link') {{ $message }} @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label class="border-b-2 border-blue-500">Image</label>
                        @if ($introSection->img_link)
                            <img src="{{ asset($introSection->img_link) }}" class="h-24 block mt-2">
                        @endif
                        @if ($photo)
                            <img src="{{ $photo->temporaryUrl() }}" class="block mt-2">
                        @endif
                        <div
                            x-data="{ progress: 0, uploading: false }"
                            @livewire-upload-start="uploading = true"
                            @livewire-upload-finish="uploading = false"
                            @livewire-upload-error="uploading = false"
                            @livewire-upload-progress="progress = $event.detail.progress">
                            <input type="file" name="img_link" wire:model="photo" class="block mt-2">
                            <progress max="100" x-bind:value="progress" x-show="uploading"></progress>
                        </div>

                        @error('photo')
                            {{ $message }}
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="md:col-span-1">
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label class="border-b-2 border-blue-500">Description</label>
                        <div class="text-lg font-medium mt-2">{{ $introSection->description }}</div>
                        <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description" wire:model="introSection.description"></textarea>
                        @error('description') {{ $message }} @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="md:col-span-1">
                    <button class="px-4 py-2 bg-blue-600 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-blue-500 active:bg-blue-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-900 focus:shadow-outline-gray disabled:opacity-25 transition ease-in-out duration-150">Save</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverted all my changes up to before I added the progress bar. The culprit seems to be the following block of code which I copied from [Livewire Added File Upload Support](https://laravel-news.com/livewire-file-upload):

```
<div
    x-data="{ progress: 0, uploading: false }"
    @livewire-upload-start="uploading = true"
    @livewire-upload-finish="uploading = false"
    @livewire-upload-error="uploading = false"
    @livewire-upload-progress="progress = $event.detail.progress">
    <input type="file" name="img_link" wire:model="photo" class="block mt-2">
    <progress max="100" x-bind:value="progress" x-show="uploading"></progress>
</div>
```

I was using Alpinejs but using @livewire directives at the same time which causes the error.

Updated code now which I got from https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads#js-hooks:

```
<div
    x-data="{ isUploading: false, progress: 0 }"
    x-on:livewire-upload-start="isUploading = true"
    x-on:livewire-upload-finish="isUploading = false"
    x-on:livewire-upload-error="isUploading = false"
    x-on:livewire-upload-progress="progress = $event.detail.progress"
                        >
    <input type="file" name="img_link" wire:model="photo" class="block mt-2">
    <div x-show="isUploading">
        <progress max="100" x-bind:value="progress"></progress>
    </div>
</div>
```